# construct functions such that $f(x)g(x)\gt0 $ and

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, functions

> Does there exist real functions $f, g\in C^1[-1,1]$ such that
>
> $$\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}f &g \\ f'&g'\end{array}\right)\equiv0 \qquad \det\left(\begin{array}{cc}\int_{-1}^1f^2\,\mathrm dx&\int_{-1}^1fg\,\mathrm dx\\\int_{-1}^1fg\,\mathrm dx&\int_{-1}^1g^2\,\mathrm dx\end{array}\right)\gt0$$
>
> and $f(x)g(x)\gt0, \, \forall x\in[-1,1]$ ?

well, I have found some functions, for example

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac1x}&0\le x\le 1\\
0&-1\leq x\lt 0
\end{cases}$$

and $g(x)=f(-x)$, but $fg\equiv0$!?

If $f(x)g(x)=0$ for some $ x\in[-1,1]$ is certainly bold,  is there a general method  to calculate all  $f$ and $g$ such that two determinants hold?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

We must $f(x)\ne0$ and $g(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then
$$
f\,g'-f'\,g=0\implies\Bigl(\frac{g}{f}\Bigr)'=0\implies g=C\,f
$$
for some constant $C>0$. Then the determinant with the integrals is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose such functions exist. The determinant condition on the integrals tells us that:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}fgdx<\sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}f^{2}(x)dx}\sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}g^{2}(x)dx}$$

The equality case of of Cauchy Schwarz tells us that $f\neq\alpha g$.

The other determinant condition tells us that the rows are linearly dependent so $f=\beta f'$ and $g=\beta g'$. Hence, $f(x)=C_{1}e^{\beta x}$ and $g(x)=C_{2}e^{\beta x}$. Since $0<fg=C_{1}C_{2}e^{2\beta x}$ then $C_{1}\neq0$ and $C_{2}\neq0$. So $f=\frac{C_{1}}{C_{2}}g$ which violates the first condition we found. Thus, no such functions exist.

Comment: the rows are not necessarily linearly dependent

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken but if the rows in that matrix were linearly independent then the matrix would be invertible. In that case I don't think the matrix could have non-zero determinant.